# Quotes not working in script

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to run the below command in a script I am making but due to the spaces the script just will not run as it does not like the syntax..can someone help me on the syntax? I have tried various combinations of double quotes, single quotes and more but it just does not like it:

```
If Not oLib.RunCommand( "REG ADD ""`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3`"" /V ""`1806`"" /T ""`REG_DWORD`"" /D ""`00000000`"" /F", True, Array(0, 3010)) Then
```

It just does not amend the registry key though..

Comment: It's the `\`` it doesn't like. Doesn't need a question to work this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
If Not oLib.RunCommand("REG ADD ""HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3"" /V ""1806"" /T ""REG_DWORD"" /D ""00000000"" /F", True, Array(0, 3010)) Then
```

OR

```
If Not oLib.RunCommand("REG ADD 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3' /V '1806' /T 'REG_DWORD' /D '00000000' /F", True, Array(0, 3010)) Then
```

If this doesn't work let us know exactly what `oLib` is and what you are trying to do,

Comment: perfect - thanks for that - the first line worked.

Comment: No explanation as to why this works? It's the `\`` if you were wondering anyone else who comes here.

Comment: I prefer answers to be detailed and explain the solution, call me old fashioned.

Comment: The thing is Fred, SO is about creating a repository of useful Q&A not just helping the OP but helping all those who come looking for a similar answer. By providing quick hit answers we are doing nothing but encouraging more low quality answers, it becomes a vicious circle.

Comment: Which is why imo this question is off topic - *"Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."*

Comment: Neither do I but there are two points, firstly the question is off topic you more a less [said that yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650793/quotes-not-working-in-script/32651006?#comment53150468_32651006) *"some answers and code corrections are so simple and evident an explanation to what changed seems a little superfluous"* and secondly knowing that you should never have answered it or if you were going to answer it make an attempt to improve the question. I'll leave it there.

Comment: @Lankymart if that is what you feel do the right thing and flag the question as off topic.

Comment: I already had before this conversation started.